# Simple app in Django. How to connect to an existing database and query it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django; intermediate in Python3.6. Now, I've created a basic Django app which displays index.html. Now, I want to create a very simple form in index.html which will query the database and print the results in the same form. I already have the postgresql database in my local with all the data needed; it is very simple with just one table (right now, my Django app is connected to the default sqlit3 db). Where do I go about creating the query to fetch the data and populate it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install these libraries first :

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

**Configuration**

in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 'db_port_number',
    }
}
```

You can refer to these two links:

1. For More Detailed information about setup :[Tutorial for setting up application using PostgreSql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. [Documentation link for writing Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

Glad you're coming on board with Django! It's a great language with plenty of useful features, you won't regret learning it.

To connect to an existing database, check out the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/). This explains how to use your existing db to create models in your project.

I also recommend checking out the tutorials in the docs starting [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/). This tutorial will explain how to connect to your postgres db, as well as how to begin writing queries for your views. This is the place to start learning the basics of Django, just follow it along and you will get the hang of everything in no time

Comment: Thank you Written. The links are very useful.